# Why does this code run in javascript ? Function inside an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

When i type this code in javascript console, this does not through an error, instead it runs.

```
var a = { 
  b:"123",
  update(){
     console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

The problem is, `update()` does not have a function keyword and when i check the properties of object `a` , i get :

```
b: "123"
update: function ()
__proto__: Object
```

What is javascript actually doing here?

Comment: ^^^^^ but only in es6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ECMA Script 6, you can define properties of an Object during its creation, without the `:`.

For example,

```
var data = 100;
var a = { data };
console.log(a);
// { data: 100 }
```

Similarly, in your case, you are creating two properties, one is called `b` and another one is called `update`, where `b` is 100 and `update` is actually a function object called `update`.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

---

**Note**: This is just the shorthand notation introduced in ECMA Script 6. You can still use the ECMA Script 5 way of creating properties which are functions, like this

```
var a = {
  b: "123",
  update: function update() {
     console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, to be precise, there are two types of shorthand object literal notation; one is called shorthand property names, the other shorthand method names, and they are relatively distinct. The latter is what the OP is wondering about.

Comment: "*In ECMA Script 6, you can define properties of an Object during its creation, without the :*" Must be noted that the *name/value* must be identical. In this case *data* within `var a = { data };` will search (within scope) for a variable *also* named data. You obviously know this, but I thought it should be pointed out for future visitors so they know what's actually going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to create a javascript object is :

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};
```

Here fullnme is a method of the object and can be accessed using:-

```
person.fullname()
```

Because of () in your code

```
var a = { 
  b:"123",
  update(){
     console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

Javascript is understanding it as a function . Hope this explanation helps.